# Serial port sharing by Java and Arduino processes

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino

I want to send an integer from my Java application to an Arduino by using the serial port, `/dev/tty.usbmodem1421`  (Mac OS X, [Mountain Lion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (v10.8), Java 6, and rxtx libraries correctly installed).
In brief, my Java application finds and opens the serial port in a correct way and adds EventListener:

```
serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(), TIME_OUT);
serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
output = serialPort.getOutputStream();
serialPort.addEventListener(this);
serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
```

And my Arduino [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) is reading from the serial port:

```
int num=0;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        num = Serial.read();

        // Code for lighting num LEDs
    }
}
```

I have two situations:

1. I launch my Java application and then my Arduino sketch
2. I launch my Arduino sketch and then my Java application

In case 1), the Arduino sketch throws PortInUse exception and in case 2) the Java application does it.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing serial monitor in Arduino. We cannot establish multiple connections to a single serial port.

When you open the serial monitor in Arduino, it will connect to the configured port number, so you cannot get access to that same port via Java code.

Comment: This is the most likely cause of the issue, especially if by "launch Arduino sketch" you mean "uploading" the sketch to Arduino. If your sketch works fine, as tested with the Serial Monitor you don't need to start the Arduino IDE - simply push the reset button on the Arduino.